# HTML5 Canvas: Prevent moving on phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I have a simple Android app, which is a HTML5 canvas.

Upon loading, the app resizes the canvas to match the window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.

However, for some reason when I hold my finger on the app and move it, i can slightly drag the whole canvas a pixel or two. Is there anyway to prevent the canvas from moving? I don't understand why it happens, the canvas should not be bigger than the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.Henderson you will need to disable the scroll event listener I.E. disable the mouse wheel, try this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) or shrink your canvas by 1 pixel width and height